# Building a user register page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to setup user registration. I have been recommended not to use scaffold.

So far I have run this command to generate model for all profile information:

```
rails generate model User name email birthday:date zip_code time_zone sexuality career education religion politics children height does_user_smoke does_user_drink about_me:text career
```

I want the required sign up information from when a user first visits the website to be name, email, birthday, zip code, and password. I am not sure what the next step is. As far as building the page to have the users sign up. I know I have to edit app/views/users/new.html.erb. When I did the tutorials I ran scaffold which did the work for me, but now I have been told by several people to not user scaffold and just do everything yourself. But I haven't read a tutorial, nor can I find any examples on the internet that will walk me through building a user register page in rails.

So I don't know if I should go back to using scaffold or hopefully someone can point me in the right direction with starting on the user register page.

Comment: Try to analyse what is generated by scaffold: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are tutorials about authentication. I personally like Ryan Bates's screencast [authentication from scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch). That tutorial should include everything you need.

As for the scaffolding, I think it really depends on what you're trying to achieve here. All scaffolding does is create the basic CRUD (create, read, update, delete) operations on a model for you, including controller, views and tests. Since you needed those views, for example, you could have used that. And prewritten tests are awesome.

However, in this case I would just go with the screencast and not use scaffolding. Scaffolding is nice for any model that doesn't need anything fancy like authentication, but only the basic CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Analise that do you want views/controllers/models or all.

Since this problem is specific to user registration, so you may only need to have user registration view and user model and the controller that performs the registration logic.

Scaffolding is useful to automate your task specifically if you want a complete MVC functionality.

For ex:

If you use the controller generator, this will generate the controller action and the view.

```
rails g controller controllername new create
```

This will create new and create actions with their relevant views.